# asp.net-core migration error on database setup

Tags: database, asp.net-core

Am trying to use code first with asp.net core api. 
When executing `Add-Migration MyFirstMigration` I get error

`System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions'1[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext]' while attempting to activate 'DAL.DataBaseContext'. at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.PopulateCallSites(ServiceProvider provider, ISet'1 callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound) at 
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.Service.CreateCallSite(ServiceProvider provider, ISet'1 callSiteChain) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetResolveCallSite(IService service, ISet'1 callSiteChain) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetServiceCallSite(Type serviceType, ISet '1 callSiteChain) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType, ServiceProvider serviceProvider) at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionaryExtensions.GetOrAdd[TKey,TValue,TArg](ConcurrentDictionary'2 dictionary, TKey key, Func'3 valueFactory, TArg arg) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType) 
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass13_2.<FindContextTypes>b__6() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func'1 factory) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.MigrationsAddCommand.Execute(CommonOptions commonOptions, String name, String outputDir, String context, String environment, Action'1 reporter)
    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.MigrationsAddCommand.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0() at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
 Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions'1[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext]' while attempting to activate 'DAL.DataBaseContext'.`

My DatabaseContext class looks like

```
public class DataBaseContext: DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public DataBaseContext(DbContextOptions<DbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ExistingProduct> ExisitingProducts { get; set; }
}
```

ConfigService like

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //Add framework services.
            var connection = @"Server=(LocalDb)\\v11.0;Database=Home;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
            services.AddDbContext<DataBaseContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
            services.AddMvc();
        }
```

In project.json tools has

```
"tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },
```

Looked into this article https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html and several different ones more but haven't figured it out. Maybe someone can help or point out what am i doing wrong?

Edited part:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.1",
    "DAL": "1.0.0-*",
    "BLL": "1.0.0-*"
  },
```

Comment: Does the dependencies section of project.json list any EntityFrameworkCore packages?

Comment: I added dependencies section to post, it should have all needed packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DbContextOptions` parameter should be `DbContextOptions<DataBaseContext>` instead of `DbContextOptions<DbContext>`.

Change the constructor of your `DataBaseContext` class.

```
public DataBaseContext(DbContextOptions<DataBaseContext> options) : base(options)
{
}
```